# Calling the overriden method from a trait with selftype

Tags: scala

Suppose, you have a trait with a selftype and you've overriden one of the methods:

```
trait A {
  def foo() { println("A") }
}

trait B { this: A =>
  override def foo() {
    println("B")
  }
}

object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val b = new A with B {}
    b.foo()
  }
}
```

So far so good, it compiles and produces "B" to the output. But how do I call the "shadowed" method from `A` to do something like this:

```
trait A {
  def foo() { println("Hello, ") }
}

trait B { this: A =>
  override def foo() {
    //here I'd like to do something like super.foo()
    println("world!")
  }
}

object Test {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val b = new A with B {}
    b.foo() //Should print "Hello, world!"
  }
}
```

Is it even possible to call overriden `foo`? Or should I prefer inheritance to selftype to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Edmondo's version:

```
scala> class C { def c = "C" }
defined class C

scala> trait T1 { def c:String }
defined trait T1

scala> trait T2 extends T1 { self:C => 
     | abstract override def c = super.c + " with T2" 
     |}
defined trait T2

scala> new C with T2
res0: C with T2 = $anon$1@1f841222

scala> res0.c
res1: java.lang.String = C with T2
```

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if `C` also extends `M`?

Comment: Perhaps, but if `C` is out of your control this way can be used.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is abstract override, which let you implement the stackable trait pattern.

If you define foo on trait A such as the following

```
trait A {
  def foo()
}

trait M extends A {
  abstract override def foo() {println("M"); super.foo()}
}

class FooImpl1 extends A {
  override def foo() {println("Impl")}
}

class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M
```

Comment: Sorry I corrected it I forgot you also need to add one class at the top of the hierarchy

Comment: And there's no selftype as well

Comment: Sorry there was a stupid typo at the last line. Class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl2 with M. Now it is class FooImpl2 extends FooImpl1 with M and everything works fine.